# Do we want hats? Winter Bash event

Tags: discussion, winterbash

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

Since then, Stack Exchange have expanded the holiday theme to any site that wants to participate.

- This year, the event will run from 14 December 2015 to 3 January 2016.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Hats will be shown to visitors by default, but logged-in users can click an "I hate hats" button to see the normal hatless avatars.
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

Sites participate unless they explicitly opt out. If you wish to opt out, reply to this post and say why. If the CS.SE community shows that it wants to sit this one out by December 9, we'll opt out. Otherwise, we're in!

Comment: I'm neutral. I don't *want* them but I don't mind if we get them.

Comment: Do the hats disappear after the event ends? (If so, then I'm in favor; I'm confident enough in my hatuality to admit that not only does gamifiation work on me, but that I actually enjoy its effects).

Comment: I always have a hat. One more won't hurt.

Comment: I share Merbs opinion. For a short period of time its probably a fun thing.

Comment: I love the idea of an "i hate hats" button, but I suppose I have to first advocate for hats so that I can get such a button...

Comment: @Merbs Yes, the hats will only be present during the event, until 4 Jan.

Comment: @Merbs Well, you know, the first step is admitting who you are and being true to yourself. Embrace it! :D

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to re-use this question to decide if we want hats in 2015. The fact that certain opinions were popular three years ago doesn't necessarily mean they're popular now, so the vote counts on the post itself and the comments could be misleading. It feels like running an election but not zeroing the vote counts after the previous one.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Given the importance of Winterbash, meh. Plus this is not an election, it's at most a plebicite (moderators were told to decide, and that they could consult the community if they wanted to — many just opted in without asking and I think a couple of sites will opt out without asking explicitly like they did the preceding years). I did zero out the vote count — there are no answers here. Feel free to express your opinion for or against hats.

Comment: @Gilles I'm in favour of hats, fwiw.

Comment: Can we add a button for those who want to get rid of the "I hate hats" button?

Comment: I like the idea of hats in addition to your your stackexhange score. It can make your seniority more visible.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks Hats are temporary. But there are also [badges](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/badges) in additional to the reputation.